# Media keys replaced by F#, how to fix?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, function-keys, fn-key, media-keys

I recently got a new [bluetooth keyboard](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00YMLG5PW/ref=s9_simh_gw_p147_d0_i1) that works fine, except for the Media keys. All of the keys in the f# row are acting as f1-f12 keys, regardless of whether the fn key is pressed or not. Is there a way to fix this? Or is that not possible, since fn/media keys are managed within the keyboard? If not, is there a way (through autoHotkey or something) to use another key (like ALT) combined with the f# keys to give the same result as the media key would have had?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is likely handled by the keyboard itself and therefore cannot be remapped.

> [Fn key - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key#Technical_details):
>
> While **it is most common for the Fn key processing to happen directly
>   in the keyboard micro-controller, offering no knowledge to the main
>   computer of whether the Fn key was pressed**, some manufacturers, like
>   Lenovo, perform this mapping in BIOS running on the main CPU, allowing
>   remapping the Fn key by modifying the BIOS interrupt handler.

AutoHotkey, as you suggested, would work as a workaround.  You would need to manually create a rule for each key (that has a <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> value).  Keep in mind that many Windows applications use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function key</kbd> keyboard shortcuts (for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to quit a program).